# Model Looks Dirty after Ambient Occlusion Bake

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I tried to AO bake my model, but it became very "dirty" with many black dots on it. How can I remove them?

[image]

Comment: Looks like overlapping geometry, do you have another object that is hidden?

Comment: @Denis Nope, all objects are in the screenshot :/

Comment: soap and water.

Comment: Looks to me like you have overlapping UVs, if not overlapping faces.

Comment: @gandalf3: oh yeah, I applied the solidify modifier to the gun by mistake :<

Comment: @gandalf3: but how can I remove the applied solidify modifier?

Comment: @AlexLing Try remove doubles (W)

Comment: @gandalf3: Thanks for reply. I've tried that and it did remove some vertices but the inner faces are still there

Comment: @AlexLing Try using a higher tolerance?